# Get smallest match using std::regex in C++

Tags: c++, regex, match

I have this  code:

```
std::smatch m;
std::string dataType = "type = struct A {\nint a;\nint b;\nint c; }";

std::regex_search(dataType, m, std::regex("(= )(.*)( [{]|\n|$)"));
std::cout << m.str(2) << std::endl;
```

The problem is that it returns the longest match, but I need the smallest.
The output is:

> ```
> struct A {\n
> int a;\n
> int b;\n
> int c; }
> ```

But it needs to be:

> struct A

How can I get the result I want?

Comment: Can you tell us more? An exmaple of the data you're parsing, an example of what the regex is matching and what do you want the regex to match?

Comment: The reason is quite possibly that regex functions work in *greedy* mode (they return the longest match). You'll have to modify the pattern to cope with more stringent searches. An example of your problem is essential here.

Comment: Ok, I edit it. Now you can see an example

Comment: My output is "struct A {". What environment are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get "struct A" from your text, the regex to be used is:

```
\=\s(\w+\s\w+)
```

if you have other cases, please give more specifications or examples of your input and how your output should look like.

**Edit:**
thanks to [user3259253](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3259253/user3259253), the correct solution is:

```
\\=\\s(\\w+(\\s\\w+)?)
```

Comment: Thanks, I for your answer. With your help I found the solution.

Comment: It is: \\=\\s(\\w+(\\s\\w+)?)

Comment: That won't work with cases such as *"type = struct A\* {..."*  Note here the \* symbol, which represents any non-alnum character.

Comment: @ DrD if there are other cases like what you mentioned, one should change the regex to suit with that ofc.

Answer (score 4):

You could change `.*` to `.*?`.

Read up on [greediness](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html).

(Did you really mean to put a literal newline in the regex? You probably want to make that `\\n`.)

Answer (score 0):

Right, use this:

```
std::regex_search(dataType, m, std::regex("(= )(.*)([\\{]|\\n)$"));
```

However, if you only what to capture what's between the *=* sign and the curly bracket/end of line, you don't need so many *()* groups. This would be enough:

```
std::regex_search(dataType, m, std::regex("= (.*)[\\{]|\\n$"));
std::cout << m.str(1) << std::endl;
```

Note that here we're catching the text as the first entry, *m.str(1)*, instead of the second, because we have eliminated *"(= )"*

Comment: Edited now so that you have the line return back, which I forgot previously. Basically you need to escape the curly bracket.